# How can I define a constant variable inside a recursive function in R?

Tags: r, recursion

I want to create functions that compute the Simple Moving Average (SMA) and the Exponential Moving Average (EMA).

My problem is in the EMA implementation. I would like to set a constant variable inside the recursive function that is equal to one of its argument.

Here is my code:

```
#SMA
sma <- function(P,t,n)
{
  return(sum(P[(t-n):(t-1)])/n)
}

#EMA
recursive.ema <- function(P,t,n)
{
  # Here I want to create a constant variable that keeps in memory the first 
  # value of t, i.e. the value of t before the first recursion, so I can use 
  # it as argument of sma function.
  # Something similar to this: tmp <- t (t given from outside the function)

  b <- 2/(n+1)
  if (t == 1)
  {
    return(b*P[1] + (1-b)*sma(P,tmp,n))
  }
  return (b*P[t] + (1-b)*recursive.ema(P,t-1,n))
}
```

Here P is a vector, time series of prices, t is the index of the vector, the time in my model,  and n is any positive number, corresponding to n lagged periods at time t.

Comment: So this doesn't work? What happens when you run this? You could also give a some example values for `P`, `t`, and `n`.

Comment: The code in the post is not complete. There is a missing part where I need help (see comments). I could create `recursive.ema <- function(P,t,n,tmp)` but I thought there is certainly a better design.

Comment: What's wrong with `tmp <- t` (or `t[1]`)?

Comment: `tmp <- t` doesn't do what I want, as `tmp` is assigned to `t` in the recursion, and thus is decremented while I want it to be constant equal to `t` value before first recursion. Likewise for `t[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work ?

```
e <-new.env()
test<-TRUE
assign("test",test,e)

recursive.ema <- function(P,t,n)
{
  test <-get("test",envir=e)
  if (test) {
    assign("t",t,envir=e)
    assign("test",FALSE,envir=e)
  } else {
    t=get("t",envir=e)
  }
  b <- 2/(n+1)
  if (t == 1)
  {
    return(b*P[1] + (1-b)*sma(P,tmp,n))
  }
  return (b*P[t] + (1-b)*recursive.ema(P,t-1,n))
}
```